# Sequencing of task using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am trying to implement logging in my SSIS package. I would like to start logging by writing a message- Batch started -- to my custom log table. I am currently having the following tasks created which run in parallel. I am thinking of creating a execute sql task which will log that. How do I tell SSIS to execute sql task before executing the other tasks in the package. Do I need to move all these tasks in a sequence container.

Please find the screenshot of my package.[image]

Comment: You can put them in any number of sequence containers and then link the containers in the order you require. Note: There are a number of ways to link containers ("Success", "Failure" and "Completion") I mostly use the default "Success". You can also include constraints to control the flow from one container to the next, See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/precedence-constraints

Comment: Is it possible that I run the tasks above in parallel and not in a sequence within the sequence container

Comment: @Tom If you move them as they currently are, they will run in parallel inside the sequence container.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I feel to implement logging is to have it in a non-intrusive manner i.e. to have them run in the background. SSIS provides this facility via 'Event Handlers'.

Open your package and go to 'Event Handlers'. With 'Executable' set as "Your Package Name", select 'OnPreExecute' as 'Event handler'. You then click on the hyperlink for you to proceed with adding the 'Execute SQL Task' for auditing.

Using the same above, you can then go on to add 'OnPostExecute'. Additionally this technique can be implemented across individual task level as well.

For more information you can refer to - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-event-handlers